# Find a quasi-random subgraph of linear size in a given graph.

Tags: extremal-combinatorics

This is a problem posed in a Problem set given by Yufei Zhao's  course 18.S997. Show that every graph contains a quasi-random subgraph of linear size. It seems that edge density increment or decrement argument doesn't work, e.g., balanced complete bipartite graph and two disjoint cliques of equal size.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: It seems that such a quasi-random subgraph is allowed to be empty.